# Is there a name for the Windows 9x/2k style of software UI design? As in, the grey-tone, grey square button, partitioned with black pinstripes?

Tags: windows, user-interface

[Image of example software here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgbt0.png)

Is there a particular name by which this style is known in UI design circles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screenshot looks more like XP/Vista.

I don't know if it had a specific name at the time, it was just how most 32-bit applications looked. All common controls and common dialogs had this look and any custom controls using `GetSysColor` would mimic it.

Going even further back, in 16-bit Windows version 1 and 2 were flat and in version 3 this "3D" look started to take over. The dialog box API for example gained the [`DS_3DLOOK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/dialog-box-styles) flag. See [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040728-00/?p=38313) for more.

These days the Windows 95 look without Visual Styles is often called "Windows Classic"/"Classic Theme".

[image: Theme select]

Comment: I think you may be right, from now on I'll refer to it as Windows Classic style/theme. Thank you :)